# MySQL - Return parent records based on conflicting WHERE clauses on child records

Tags: mysql, sql

I am a database with the following tables:

Orders, Lines, Suppliers

The lines table has FKs to the Orders and Lines table:

order_id, supplier_id

I am trying to write a query which will return a count of the order records which have at least one line from a certain supplier but no lines from any other suppliers.

So, an order which only has 1 line, but that line is from the given supplier would be counted.

On the other hand, an order with 100 lines from the given supplier but just one from any other supplier would not be counted.

I can count the orders with at least one line easily enough but I'm stuck on excluding the ones with lines from other suppliers.

```
SELECT
COUNT(DISTINCT(orders.id)) AS count
FROM orders
INNER JOIN lines
ON lines.order_id = orders.id
WHERE
lines.supplier_id = 1
```

Is there an easy way to do this (preferably without a subquery, as what I have here is already part of a much larger query)?

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rough pre-coffee guess:

```
SELECT orders.id, SUM(lines.supplier_id = 1) AS wanted,
    SUM(lines.supplier_id <> 1) AS unwanted
FROM orders
INNER JOIN lines lines.order_id = orders.id
GROUP BY orders.id
HAVING unwanted = 0 AND wanted > 0
```

Basically: grab all the orders and use a handy mysql hack where the above SUMs take the boolean results of your supplier ID comparisons and auto-cast them to integer `1` and `0`. Use this "count" to figure out which orders contain your desired supplier, and a "sum" of 0 for any other suppliers.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) from orders o
where exists (
    select 1 from lines l
    where l.order_id = o.id
    and l.supplier_id = 1
) and not exists (
    select 1 from lines l
    where l.order_id = o.id
    and l.supplier_id <> 1
)
```

This query can take advantage of an index on `lines(order_id,supplier_id)`